# Can't get bottle to run on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bottle

I've got a website written in [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/) and I'd like to deploy it via Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk. I followed the [tutorial for deploying flask](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_flask.html) which I hoped would be similar.
I tried to adapt the instructions to bottle by making the requirements.txt this:

```
bottle==0.11.6
```

and replaced the basic flask version of the application.py file with this:

```
from bottle import route, run
@route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I updated to this version as instructed in the tutorial, and when I wrote `eb status` it says it's green, but when I go to the URL  nothing loads. It just hangs there. I tried the run() method at the end as it is shown above and also how it is written in the bottle hello world application (ie `run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)`) and neither seemed to work. I also tried both `@route('/hello')` as well as the `@route('/')`.

I went and did it with flask instead (ie exactly like the Amazon tutorial says) and it worked fine. Does that mean I can't use bottle with elastic beanstalk? Or is there something I can do to make it work?

Thanks a lot,
Alex

EDIT:
With aychedee's help, I eventually got it to work using the following application file:

```
from bottle import route, run, default_app
application = default_app()
@route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello bottle World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it possible that the WSGI server is looking for `application` variable inside `application.py`? That's how I understand it works for Flask.

```
application = bottle.default_app()
```

The application variable here is a [WSGI application as specified in PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/). It's a callable that takes the environment and a start_response function.  So the Flask, and Bottle WSGI application have exactly the same interface.

Possibly... But then I'm confused as to why you need that **and** the call to `run`.

Comment: Hmm maybe, does beanstalk use its own wsgi server or the one built into flask (or bottle)? The hello world program [for flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/) involves making that application object, while [the one for bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html) doesn't. Not sure if I could make an application object like that for bottle as well somehow and that might work?

Comment: Yup, you can try. The line I included in my answer is how you get the WSGI app from the bottle framework.

Comment: Ok, I did that and got a little further but now it's giving me an "Internal Server Error", and it says `Apache/2.2.22 (Amazon) Server at test-env-ppamp7m3yc.elasticbeanstalk.com Port 80` at the bottom. I didn't know I was even running Apache, isn't it supposed to be running its own test server thing?

Comment: Cool, so that does fix it. Now you have a different problem, you should mark this question as answered and ask again with your new symptoms. I'm not going to do Q&A in the comments. Though I will say that the first thing you need to do is read about how to enable logging (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html). The stacktrace that you need to read to fix this problem will only show up in a logfile.

Comment: Oh and yes, Elastic Beanstalk is built on Apache and Mod wsgi.