# Can't load static files with bottle on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bottle

After [some help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258044/cant-get-bottle-to-run-on-elastic-beanstalk), I got my bottle application running with Elastic Beanstalk. Well almost - I still can't see any static files. I have followed the instructions [here](http://blog.uptill3.com/2012/08/25/python-on-elastic-beanstalk.html) by inserting a file called python.conf in directory .ebextensions with this in it:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static/"
```

Unfortunately that did not work. My files are in folders under /static (for example, /static/js, /static/css etc). In my bottle application, I was serving static files as per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693695/loading-static-files-in-a-bottle-py-application-on-openshift), like this:

```
@route('/static/:path#.+#')
def server_static(path):
    return static_file(path, root='./static')
```

It all works when I run it locally. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Should I be following a different procedure because my static files are in subfolders, or because I'm using bottle instead of flask? I'm aware of [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077489/static-assets-dont-show-up-for-flask-on-elastic-beanstalk) that has been asked here for flask, but there has been no answer (and for all I know it could be a totally different issue).
Thanks a lot, Alex

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried using an absolute path instead of a relative one in `root='./static'`?

Comment: hmm no I haven't. To be honest I'm not even sure what the static path would be on the instance, it would clearly be different from my local copy. Would a solution be to host the static files on S3 instead? Could I just use the unique url for each of those items? I guess I'd have to go back into all html and switch it to S3 addresses, but that wouldn't be that difficult at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it isn't the most elegant solution, but I solved this by putting all of my static files in an S3 bucket and using that in all of my pages.

I didn't really have that many static files to begin with so it wasn't a very big deal. I just made a variable of the S3 bucket url:

`S3Static = r'mystaticbucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'`

Passed it to my bottle templates, and changed the links from:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "/static/css/MarmoStyle.css" >`

to

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "{{S3Static}}/static/css/Style.css">`

(ie just added {{S3Static}} before the path)
If you're using a static file in a separate %included header template like I am, you have to pass the S3Static variable to the template like this:

`%include header.tpl S3Static=S3Static`

And that was about it. I know this won't be an ideal solution for everyone and there are probably better ways to do it, but it's worked for me so far.
Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

You should really look into python's whitenoise module.  Then you only have one line you have to change and the URL routing is handled by whitenoise next to bottle.  Essentially you can keep the url the same as your domain, even if whitenoise is pulling from someplace else.  PLus it's designed to cache your static data.  Definitely should be using it.  It takes like 3 lines to setup, and you can remove bottle's static folder route.